# Reading response from SOAP, XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm having a problem with properly addressing bellow SOAP response, I think it's due to " part...

Can anyone could show me an example how I could refer to "DSPTrackingNumber" ?

```
   $xml_resp = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
       <soap:Body>
       <ns2:GenerateLabelResponse 
       xmlns:ns2='http://cpgm.dpdhl.com/returnit/ws/generate_label'>
       <label>base64</label>
       <DSPTrackingNumber>409388775152</DSPTrackingNumber>
       <responseText>Label generated.</responseText>
       <responseCode>0</responseCode>
       </ns2:GenerateLabelResponse>
       </soap:Body>
       </soap:Envelope>";
```

**EDIT: I tried this.**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_resp);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns2", "http://cpgm.dpdhl.com/returnit/ws/generate_label");

$RespData = $xml->xpath("//ns2");

echo "DSPTrackingNumber=".$RespData->DSPTrackingNumber;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? How about http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ?

Comment: @Sammitch yes I tried couple of options, though I think the closest one is the one with registerXPathNamespace, but I'm probably getting the Namespace wrong... I edited my first post. Thanks for guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the DSPTrackingNumber, then you don't need to use the namespace, as it's not used in the element.

So -

```
$xml_resp = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
       <soap:Body>
       <ns2:GenerateLabelResponse
       xmlns:ns2='http://cpgm.dpdhl.com/returnit/ws/generate_label'>
       <label>base64</label>
       <DSPTrackingNumber>409388775152</DSPTrackingNumber>
       <responseText>Label generated.</responseText>
       <responseCode>0</responseCode>
       </ns2:GenerateLabelResponse>
       </soap:Body>
       </soap:Envelope>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_resp);

//$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns2", "http://cpgm.dpdhl.com/returnit/ws/generate_label");

$RespData = $xml->xpath("//DSPTrackingNumber");

echo "DSPTrackingNumber=".$RespData[0];
```

gives...

```
DSPTrackingNumber=409388775152
```